# How to scale transactional outbox pattern with document database?

Tags: domain-driven-design, microservices, cqrs, mongodb, document-databases

I'm trying to understand CQRS, DDD by writing a small pet project which is somewhat similar to [this](https://github.com/kgrzybek/modular-monolith-with-ddd/tree/master) great repo.

I've come across [Transactional Outbox](https://microservices.io/patterns/data/transactional-outbox.html) pattern and as imo it was correctly pointed out in [this](https://pradeepl.com/blog/transactional-outbox-pattern/) article it looks hard to scale this approach to even thousands active users when using document oriented databases, because one would have to read all the changes in the database periodically, blocking the events with non-empty domainEvents list. The solution in the article is to use change streams (in MongoDB terminology), but they can not be reliably read from multiple hosts concurrently w/o duplication of events.

The only fix I see right now is to come up with some trickery in the changeStream query to "shard" events across machines and then put them in the message broker. Am I missing anything? Or is there a document oriented db that allows to "shard" eventStreams?

P.S. Since the MongoDB supports multi-collection transactions, another way around would be to use Outbox implementation for relational databases e.g. committing events in separate collection and reading from it. If I understand correctly, in this approach one application instance should be able to handle change stream of a single replica set.

Answer (score 4):

In this answer I do not dive into MongoDB technology and how to mitigate issues with duplicates manually. I explain what was referenced in the article (Debezium), suggest to use out of the box solutions and mention other patterns than transactional outbox.

### Debezium

If you are willing to use Kafka as your message broker then there is a project called [Debezium](https://debezium.io/) which is based on Kafka Connect.

*Small note here - there is a feature called Debezium Server which doesn't require Kafka nor Kafka Connect, but it is currently (1.9) in incubating state.*

It has a [MongoDB connector](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/stable/connectors/mongodb.html), so you can just point it at your MongoDB instance. With [MongoDB Outbox Event Router](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/stable/transformations/mongodb-outbox-event-router.html) the implementation of the transactional outbox pattern is (almost) just a matter of proper configuration. Personally I've used Debezium and it worked, but it may be challenging to get the configuration right first time.

### Duplicates

About duplicates. Debezium does the work for you and really tries to not send duplicate messages, but keep in mind that your consumers should always be prepared to receive duplicate messages. From the docs:

> When everything is operating nominally, Kafka consumers will actually see every message exactly once. However, when things go wrong Kafka can only guarantee consumers will see every message at least once. Therefore, your consumers need to anticipate seeing messages more than once.

It's near to impossible to achieve exactly-once delivery in a distributed system, although there is some magic trickery you can do with Kafka like enabling exactly-once semantics.
Still, in real-world applications your consumers should be idempotent and [here](https://blog.bulloak.io/post/20200917-the-impossibility-of-exactly-once/) is a good article why.

### Scalability

The transactional outbox using change streams or any other form of CDC - Change Data Capture mechanism is currently the most scalable option if you are writing to the DB first and then later want to send a message - addressing dual writes problem. It can use low-level database features, so with proper DB technology the messages are published almost in real-time with minimal performance hit on the DB itself.

However, there is also a [listen to yourself pattern](https://medium.com/@odedia/listen-to-yourself-design-pattern-for-event-driven-microservices-16f97e3ed066), where you write to the message broker instead of writing to the DB.

*If you don't want the message to be visible immediately to "others" (parallel is not an option) then you can have an internal consumer that listens to those messages, writes to the DB and maybe after that you can publish the message further for "others" - notice that you need to record the fact that you processed the message **after** publishing it further (commit/ack to the message broker) and your own internal consumer must be idempotent - it can receive duplicates when something fails after writing to the DB.*

This way you are not tied to the specific DB technology, so you do not really care if it is a relational or document databse. It can scale really well, but it has its own drawbacks too - the state of the system is not so obvious, should you backup now your message broker data too? and so on. The solution really depends on what you are trying to achieve.

There are even some ideas of using Event Sourcing and Event Store itself as a message broker... This solution and others are described in [this red hat article](https://developers.redhat.com/articles/2021/09/21/distributed-transaction-patterns-microservices-compared#the_modular_monolith).

[image]
[image]

### Horizontal scaling with Debezium

Usually you want your messages / events to be processed in order only within some boundaries. If you can identify areas in your Domain that can be processed in parallel then you can create separate event streams and you could in theory configure multiple Debezium connectors per area / Bounded Context or maybe even per Aggregate. It really depends on your Domain and required throughput. However, more connectors means higher load on the DB, so there is a tradeoff. Keep in mind that single Debezium connector can actually handle a lot and you can still process things in parallel on the other side (sink) of Debezium - in Kafka realm you do this by setting proper partition keys:

> The MongoDB connector does not make any explicit determination about
> how to partition topics for events. Instead, it allows Kafka to
> determine how to partition topics based on event keys. You can change
> Kafka’s partitioning logic by defining the name of the Partitioner
> implementation in the Kafka Connect worker configuration.
>
> Kafka maintains total order only for events written to a single topic
> partition. Partitioning the events by key does mean that all events
> with the same key always go to the same partition. This ensures that
> all events for a specific document are always totally ordered.

Debezium connector doesn't do a lot of CPU work, it's mostly I/O.
So if you don't have a particular reason to jump into multi-connector setup then don't do it. Start with single connector and distribute your events with proper partition keys, so you can horizontally scale your consumers. What is interesting, by default the partition key field in *MongoDB Outbox Event Router* is called *aggregateid*.

### Final notes

If you can use Debezium then go for it. There is a lot of stuff in the docs about how it actually works with MongoDB, what are the requirements etc:

> ...operations on the actual business collection(s) and the insert into the outbox collection must be done as part of a multi-document transaction, which have been being supported since MongoDB 4.0, to prevent potential data inconsistencies between business collection(s) and outbox collection. For future update, to enable updating existing data and inserting outbox event in an ACID transaction without multi-document transactions, we have planned to support additional configurations for storing outbox events in a form of a sub-document of the existing collection, rather than an independent outbox collection.
>
> ...With change streams, the MongoDB server exposes changes to
> collections as an event stream. The Debezium connector watches the
> stream and delivers the changes downstream. And, when the connector
> sees a replica set for the first time, it looks at the oplog to get
> the last recorded transaction and then performs a snapshot of the
> primary’s databases and collections. When all the data is copied, the
> connector then creates a change stream from the position it read
> earlier from the oplog... The MongoDB connector is also quite tolerant
> of changes in membership and leadership of the replica sets, of
> additions or removals of shards within a sharded cluster, and network
> problems that might cause communication failures. The connector always
> uses the replica set’s primary node to stream changes, so when the
> replica set undergoes an election and a different node becomes
> primary, the connector will immediately stop streaming changes,
> connect to the new primary, and start streaming changes using the new
> primary node. Likewise, if connector experiences any problems
> communicating with the replica set primary, it will try to reconnect
> (using exponential backoff so as to not overwhelm the network or
> replica set) and continue streaming changes from where it last left
> off. In this way the connector is able to dynamically adjust to
> changes in replica set membership and to automatically handle
> communication failures.

Comment: > CDC - Change Data Capture mechanism is currently the most scalable option. Yes, my concern is that it introduces a single point of failure, if I'm not using something on top of that like Kafka Connect or Debezium
---- 
> However, there is also a listen to yourself pattern, where you write to the message broker instead of writing to the DB. For this to work there should be a way to merge conflicts in events and I would really like to avoid that.

Comment: thank you for such a detailed answer!